# Would this be considered a memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, fork, execv

Consider this pointless program:

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        int pid = fork();
        int status;
        if (pid) {
            wait(&status);
        }
        else {
            char *ptr = (char *)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
            char *args[2] = {"Hello, world!", NULL};
            execve("/bin/echo", args, NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Would not freeing `ptr` constitute a memory leak for either main.c or the other program, or is it going to be freed anyway when execve is called?

Comment: I'd sleep better with `free(ptr);` before the execve

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No.**

This is not a memory leak.  `exec*()` will make a local copy of the string data in the args array, then blow away the child process memory image and overlay it with the memory image used by `/bin/echo`.  Essentially all that remains after the exec() is the pid.

Edit:

User318904 brought up the case of exec() returning -1 (i.e., failure).  In this case, the child process that has forked but failed to exec does, indeed technically have a memory leak, but as the usual response to a failed exec is to just exit the child process anyways, the memory will be reclaimed by the OS.  Still, freeing it is probably a good habit to get into, if for no other reason than that it will keep you from wondering about it later on.

Comment: Thanks. It's not an issue of my being too lazy to add free(ptr). In the actual, slightly-more-complicated case that I have in my real program, I'm actually passing a malloc'ed string to execve, so I'm unable to free it (though I do call free if execve fails).

Comment: @Nick:  The source of the memory (stack, heap, static) is irrelevant to the OS--it's all just memory, and it will be replaced and reclaimed automatically and painlessly by the OS.

Answer (score 3):

When execve returns -1, yes. Otherwise, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The allocated memory should be freed by `exec`. After the call completes you can't access it anyway.